# Executing the &block in method_missing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, block, method-missing

I've just began learning about blocks and using `method_missing` in Ruby classes, and I've noticed the general formula is

```
def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
```

My question is if it's possible to execute the `&block` in the output. For example:

```
class Foo
  def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
     puts "#{sym} was called with #{args} and returned #{block.call(args)}"
  end
end

bar = Foo.new
bar.test(1,2,3, lambda {|n| n + 2} )
```

Is there a way to make this work so that the block returns a new array?

Comment: @CarySwoveland the link doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: [Here](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) is a nice article on the differences among blocks, procs and lambdas.  (punkinbread: the link should be OK now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you want this:

```
class Foo
  def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
     puts "#{sym} was called with #{args} and returned #{block.call(args)}"
  end
end

bar = Foo.new
bar.test(1,2,3) do |a| 
  a.map{|e| e + 2}
end
```

Execution result:

```
test was called with [1, 2, 3] and returned [3, 4, 5]
```

Updated: yield can be used as below.

```
 puts "#{sym} was called with #{args} and returned #{yield(args) if block_given?}"
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for! Could this also be done using `yield`?

Comment: Yes,it can be done using yield. I update the answer using yield.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do something like this?

```
def foo(*args, &block)
  args.map(&block)
end

foo(1, 2, 3) { |n| n + 2 } #=> [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually helps a lot too. Could this also be done using `yield`?